# How I will do load test(vegeta) for multiple methods multiple in golang

Tags: go, postman, load-testing, go-gin

Suppose I have an api having two routes one is for saving the user and another one is for getting the user given below:-

router.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "go-training/postAPI/controller"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc func(*gin.Context)
}

type Routes []Route

var routes = Routes{
    Route{"SaveUser", "POST", "/post", controller.SaveUser},
    Route{"GetUser", "GET", "/post/:id", controller.GetUser},
}
func NewRouter() {
    router := gin.Default()
    v1 := router.Group("/api/v1")
    for _, route := range routes {
        switch route.Method {
        case "GET":
            v1.GET(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
        case "POST":
            v1.POST(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
        case "PUT":
            v1.PUT(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
        case "DELETE":
            v1.DELETE(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
        default:
            v1.GET(route.Pattern, func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                    "result": "Specify a valid http method with this route.",
                })
            })
        }
    }
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

By hitting these url `localhost:8080/api/v1/post` method:- `POST` by Postman it will take the json data from postman and enters into the database and while getting the user url `localhost:8080/api/v1/post/:id` method:- `GET` by postman then it will return the user matching with the id entered. Now, I want to take load test(vegeta) these api's because I want to see that how many request it would be take in one second. I read [this link](https://thisdata.com/blog/load-testing-api-interfaces-with-go-and-vegeta/) and implement the program but I don't know how will I take load test of my api's separately.

Can anyone tell me that how will I take the load test of these two api's or any refrence?

**Edited**

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    NewRouter()
    GetVegeta()
}
```

vegeta.go

```
// Panic if there is an error
func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
func GetVegeta() {
    var (
        users int
    )

    // The Go random number generator source is deterministic, so we need to seed    
    // Configure our command line app
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "Pokemon User Data Generator"
    app.Usage = "generate a stream of test data for vegeta. Type 'pokemon help' for details"

    // Add -users flag, which defaults to 5
    app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
        cli.IntFlag{
            Name: "users",
        },
    }

    // Our app's main action
    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
    // Combine verb and URL to a target for Vegeta
        verb := c.Args().Get(0)
        url := c.Args().Get(1)
        target := fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", verb, url)
        fmt.Println(verb)
        fmt.Println(url)
        fmt.Println(target)
        if len(target) > 1 {

            for i := 1; i < users; i++ {
                fmt.Println(users)
            }
        } else {
            // Return an error if we're missing the required command line arguments
            return cli.NewExitError("You must specify the target in format 'VERB url'", 1)
        }
        return nil
    }

    app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

These files are in same folder name `Template`. I'm running this whole folder with the command `./Template -users=10 GET https://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer | vegeta attack -rate=10 -duration=30s | vegeta report`

by running this all api's run and when I will hit any api from the postman then it will give me the **error** of `bad method: [GIN]` and `encode: can't detect encoding of "stdin"` How will I solve this to make a report of my api's.

Thanks for your precious time!

Comment: Could you show us vegata file you have written?

Comment: @mbuechmann see the edit I edit my question

Comment: Hi @misha You have included your whole program. That is a start. However, your question would be much easier to answer if you would reduce your code to the relevant part. See [mcve]

Comment: @mbuechmann will you tell me that is there any reference program from which I will under vegeta attack that how to implement it in go to test multiple routes.

Comment: There is no such thing. Just use common sense and ask yourself: "Is this part relevant"? E.g. your main func is not relevant. Your routing is not relevant, at least not all routes. All those fmt.Printlns, too, and so on.

Comment: Also: more important would be, on which lines your errore occurs. You should add a comment in the source code. Do you get them during run time or compile time?

Comment: @mbuechmann yes sir,I got the run time error

Answer (score -2):

Vegeta takes concurrency and time parameters and you can create report out of it.

Answer (score -2):

you could use 
 https://linux.die.net/man/1/siege and it allow you to test APIs and having report